# Why do the references to my custom objects become null when accessed by a member method?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app, written purely in Java (no NDK), in Android Studio. The app began crashing a few days ago and telling me that I was trying to invoke an abstract class method on a null object reference. The object references the output console was referring to, however, are only modified once (when they are instantiated for the first time).

I have a custom class named `RecipeEditor` that contains private member object arrays of two other custom classes: `IngredientSelector` and `GraphBar`. When I instantiate `RecipeEditor`, it instantiates both the array of `IngredientSelector` objects and `GraphBar` objects one by one.

Both `RecipeEditor` and `IngredientSelector` contain a method,  `updateValues()`. When an `IngredientSelector` object is instantiated, it is passed a reference to the `RecipeEditor` object it belongs to. Furthermore, when the `IngredientSelector` object calls `updateValues()` within itself, it updates a few variables and then calls the `updateValues()` function of the `RecipeEditor` object passed to it earlier.

This is where things get screwy: the `updateValues()` function in the `RecipeEditor` object crashes the app when it tries to call the `setBarValue()` method contained within the GraphBar class. Even worse, the debugger says that both the array of `IngredientSelector` objects and the array of `GraphBar` objects are null. To make things even more bizarre, the objects that were once contained in the arrays *still exist in memory.* I know this because the objects still function onscreen.

---

`RecipeEditor` class:

```
package darnell.coldpresstycoon;

import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import darnell.coldpresstycoon.Dialogs.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Darnell on 4/8/2017.
 */

public class RecipeEditor {
    private View layout;

    private Recipe recipe;

    private TextView ouncesRemaining;
    private int ouncesRemainingValue = 16;

    private IngredientSelector[] ingredientSelectors = new IngredientSelector[3];

    private GraphBar[] graphBars = new GraphBar[4];

    public RecipeEditor(View layout, ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients, Recipe recipe) {
        this.layout = layout;

        this.recipe = recipe;

        ouncesRemaining = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ouncesRemaining);

        ingredientSelectors[0] = new IngredientSelector(
                layout.findViewById(R.id.ingredientSelector1),
                this,
                recipe,
                0);

        ingredientSelectors[1] = new IngredientSelector(
                layout.findViewById(R.id.ingredientSelector2),
                this,
                recipe,
                1);

        ingredientSelectors[2] = new IngredientSelector(
                layout.findViewById(R.id.ingredientSelector3),
                this,
                recipe,
                2);

        graphBars[0] = new GraphBar(layout.findViewById(R.id.sweetness),
                "SWEETNESS",
                recipe);

        graphBars[1] = new GraphBar(layout.findViewById(R.id.sourness),
                "SOURNESS",
                recipe);

        graphBars[2] = new GraphBar(layout.findViewById(R.id.flavor),
                "FLAVOR",
                recipe);

        graphBars[3] = new GraphBar(layout.findViewById(R.id.novelty),
                "NOVELTY",
                recipe);

        updateValues();
    }

    //Getters
    public int getOuncesRemainingValue() {
        return ouncesRemainingValue;
    }

    public void updateValues() {

        //Calculate ounces remaining
        ouncesRemainingValue = 16-recipe.getQuantitySum();

        //Set ounces remaing string
        ouncesRemaining.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", ouncesRemainingValue));

        //Adjust color of ouncesRemaing TextView to reflect value
        if(ouncesRemainingValue == 0)
            ouncesRemaining.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(layout.getContext(),
                    R.color.colorTextBright));
        else
            ouncesRemaining.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(layout.getContext(),
                    R.color.colorTextLight));

        //Update sweetness
        graphBars[0].setBarValue(0.3f);

    }
}
```

---

`IngredientSelector` `updateValues()` method:

```
public void updateValues(int quantityValue) {
    quantity.setText(String.format(Locale.US,
            "%d ounce%s",
            quantityValue,
            quantityValue == 1 ? "" : "s"));

    totalCost.setText(String.format(Locale.US,
            "$%3.2f",
            quantityValue*ingredient.getPricePerOunce()));

    recipe.setQuantityValue(index, quantityValue);
    recipeEditor.updateValues();
}
```

---

`GraphBar` `setBarValue()` method:

```
public void setBarValue(float value) {
    //final TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, );
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            value);

    //params = (TableRow.LayoutParams) filled.getLayoutParams();
    //params.weight = value;
    filled.setLayoutParams(params);

    //empty.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
            //TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            //1.0f-value));
}
```

---

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void darnell.coldpresstycoon.GraphBar.setBarValue(float)' on a null object reference
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.RecipeEditor.updateValues(RecipeEditor.java:93)
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.IngredientSelector.updateValues(IngredientSelector.java:92)
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.IngredientSelector.<init>(IngredientSelector.java:60)
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.RecipeEditor.<init>(RecipeEditor.java:35)
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.Dialogs.RecipeDialog.<init>(RecipeDialog.java:40)
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96)
```

---

I'm new to Stack Overflow as a member, so I apologize if my question is oddly formatted or too verbose.

Comment: Add the stack trace for more info

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sigrist I've updated my question with the stack trace included.

Comment: @Andreas My apologies. I just edited the question the best I could for brevity (with the exception of the stack trace).

Comment: Please reformat the stack trace so it is on the same planet as the rest of us.

Comment: @EJP I have returned the stack trace to earth at your behest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the call stack in the stacktrace:

```
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.RecipeEditor.updateValues(RecipeEditor.java:93)
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.IngredientSelector.updateValues(IngredientSelector.java:92)
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.IngredientSelector.<init>(IngredientSelector.java:60)
at darnell.coldpresstycoon.RecipeEditor.<init>(RecipeEditor.java:35)
```

The `RecipeEditor` constructor calls the `IngredientSelector` constructor, which calls `IngredientSelector.updateValues()`, which calls `RecipeEditor.updateValue()`, *before* the construction of the `RecipeEditor` is done.

The array hasn't been initialized yet.

Re-think your logic.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to do the trick! This is definitely one of those situations that makes me feel stupid when I realize the error I made.